# Making an image stay in the new position after being moved

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript code that makes an image move horizontally for an interval of time then stop. I want the image to stay in the new position without going back to its previous place.

This is the code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var imgObj = null;
     var animate ;

     function init(){
         imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
         imgObj.style.position= 'relative'; 
         imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
     }

     function moveRight(){
         imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
         animate = setTimeout(moveRight,20); // call moveRight in 20msec
         setTimeout(stop, 350);
     }

     function stop(){
         clearTimeout(animate);
         imgObj.style.left = '0px'; 
     }

     window.onload =init;
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="moveRight();"><img id="myImage" src="book_cover.jpg"/></a>
```

Comment: why not just removing the line imgObj.style.left = '0px' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var imgObj;
var elapsed = 0;

function init(){
    imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
    imgObj.style.position = 'relative';
    imgObj.style.left = '0px';
}

function moveRight(){
    imgObj.style.left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left) + 10 + 'px';
    elapsed += 20;
    if (elapsed < 350) setTimeout(moveRight, 20);
}

window.onload = init;
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="moveRight()">
    <img id="myImage" src="https://placeimg.com/60/80/tech" width="60" height="80" />
</a>
```